# Windows wsl without swap file

Tags: windows-10, wsl2

I am thinking to set swap configuration in `.wslconfig` to zero. This is not for production just for development and to decrease disk operations, so:

1. Is it supported to set swap size to zero?
2. Is it stable?
3. If docker container has some write operations to swap file - will they be redirected to ram?

Comment: When you set it to zero, start the WSL instance since it requires it to be shutdown and restarted, does it then indicate the swap space is unallocated or allocated to 0? If there isn't swap configured, even on a physical machine, all applications would be limited to the physical memory capabilites of the machine.

Comment: Programs, including these running in containers, don't choose between writing to RAM or swap. They don't see the difference, and OS manages what goes where.